# Centrar respecto a su contenedor un elemento inline entre otros dos elementos inline

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un problema que no logro solucionar, y es dentro de un contenedor con tres elementos  inline. Centrar el elemento que esta entre los otros dos respecto al ancho de su contenedor.

Teniendo lo siguiente:

```
<div>
   <a style="float: left;"><span style="mis estilos">uno</span></a>
   <a style="margin: auto 0;"><span style="mis estilos">dos</span></a>
   <a style="float: right;"><span style="mis estilos">tres</span></a>
</div>
```

Poniendo en el estilo del elemento central lo siguiente:

```
margin: auto 0;
```

o

```
text-align: center;
```

o

```
position: absolute; margin: auto 0;
```

en un navegador de escritorio parece funcionar. Pero en el navegador del móvil el elemento se me coloca centrado al ancho del espacio entre los otros dos en vez de al ancho a todo su contenedor.

Comment: ¿Has intentado hacerlo con flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una solución que creo que te podría valer. Consiste básicamente en darle un ancho a cada columna y centrar el contenido de cada una de ellas en función de las necesidades que planteas. Al ser un tamaño porcentual da igual en que dispositivo te encuentres siempre ocupara el mismo. Espero que te sea útil:

```
.redistribuye {display: flex;}
.redistribuye a{align-items: center; width: 33%}
.redistribuye a.left{text-align: left; background-color: red; color: #fff}
.redistribuye a.center{text-align: center; background-color: orange; color: #fff}
.redistribuye a.right{text-align: right; background-color: green; color: #fff}
```

`<div class="redistribuye">
   <a class="left">uno</a>
    <a class="center">dos</a>
    <a class="right">tres</a>
</div>`

Comment: Gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con propiedades flexbox:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <a><span style="mis estilos">uno</span></a>
    <a><span style="mis estilos">dos</span></a>
    <a><span style="mis estilos">tres</span></a>
</div>
```

También puedes probar cambiando por `space-around` para que te ponga más márgenes.

Como lo que requieres debe centrar el segundo el elemento con respecto al ancho de su contendor, deberías hacerlo con un `margin-left` o `margin-right`:

```html
<div>
    <a style="float: left;"><span style="mis estilos">uno</span></a>
    <a style="margin-left: 40%;"><span style="mis estilos">dos</span></a>
    <a style="float: right;"><span style="mis estilos">tres</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: No me funciona, en los navegadores de escritorio los elementos me los situa bien centrado pero en el móvil el elemento central me lo situa centrado respecto al ancho del espacio entre el elemento de la izquierda y el elemento de la derecha. Solo se me ocurre posicionar el elemento que tiene que ir centrado con un position:absolute y un right: 50% - ( el ancho del elemento central div 2) pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Correcto, el centro será respecto al espacio disponible entre los elementos de los extremos, sin embargo dependiendo de tu objetivo esta sería la mejor forma de presentar los elementos.  He editado la respuesta para hacer lo que sugieres.

Comment: Pero en cambio  el navegador de PC el elemento central lo posiciona en la mitad del ancho del contenedor.